# Can't take an instance using Controls.Add

Tags: c#, events, button, instance

I'm triyng to create buttons programmatically. I don't want to use Button btn = new Button();.. btn.height=.... control.Add(btn);. The code I'm using can add the buttons to the form but I can't take an instance so I can't create button.click event. Can anybody help me to solve it. The code I'm using below thanks.

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        Controls.Add( 
            new Button() 
            { 
                Top = 50 + (50 * i), 
                Left = 50 + (50 * j), 
                Width = 50, Height = 50, 
                Text = (++k).ToString()
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: You say you dont want to use `Button button = new Button();` But why not?

Comment: You also say you **can't** take an instance. The code you are showing can do that.

Comment: That was a part of an quiz and everybody used the same way to create the buttons including me. Just want to learn the different ways.

Comment: While @Tor s answer does work its not really usual as you practically have the control in the for loop. It would be a bit of a performance hit (not much) but for practice its good :)

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a button, and subscribe directly to the event (i don't know why is this important), you can do this:

```
private void Method()
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            Controls.Add(new Button() { Top = 50 + (50 * i), Left = 50 + (50 * j), Width = 50, Height = 50, Text = (++k).ToString() });
        }
    }
    Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.Click += Button_Click);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((sender as Button).Text);
}
```